# HTML5 + CSS3 VS Standard HTML 4

Tags: html, css

As looking around the internet I am not able to find the desired comparison of HTML5 and standard HTML4. I know some of advantages of HTML5 like multimedia and new components etc. But I am looking for a nice comparison of both of these. For example I have following questions in my mind.

- What are the major advantages of HTML5 over standard HTML4 (I know of many)
- What are disadvantages of using HTML5 (Except it does not work before IE9)
- What are the advantages and disadvantages using HTML5 with CSS3 over standar HTML4 with CSS.

Here I am looking for both the advantages and disadvantages of using HTML5 and CSS3.

Thanks for time.

Comment: HTML5 is HTML that uses elements/styles from version 5 of HTML standard... It is unclear what you want to compare it to...

Comment: I mean comparison of version 4 and 5. My bad

Comment: I'm not sure anyone even used HTML 4 anymore in their doctype. A better comparison might be between XHTML 1.0 T/s and/or XHTML 1.1 versus HTML 5

Comment: I am new to this world. I am talking about the HTML we used before the arrival of HTML5. I don't know if it makes sense

Comment: When you produce HTML4 you are actually producing HTML5 (HTML5 is superset of HTML4). There is no such thing as HTML4 vs HTML5. HTML5 (as well as CSS3) is additions to already available technology. In other words, you can chose to include features from HTML5 but you cannot produce anything that is HTML5 but not HTML4.

Comment: OK, so, the question should be then "what are the advantages and disadvantages of using HTML5 components"

Comment: In that case I would say that the advantage of using HTML5 components be that you can do things with it that you can't with 4. Disadvantage being that old (versions of) browsers do not support it.

Comment: This type of design question is likely to solicit debate and isn't a good fit for the *technical* Q&A format of StackOverflow. As such it's likely to be closed. However, it is the right subject-matter for Programmers.StackExchange.com - you should ask it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short:

**Advantages:**

- Support for interactive media
- Improved semantics
- More intuitive development

**Disadvantages:**

- Supported only on modern browsers

First, it's key to remember that the language itself is not considered finished.  Thus, HTML5 is a continuation of earlier versions and is considered an improvement of the language.

As you alluded in your question, the major disadvantage of HTML5 is that it's only supported by modern browsers (see http://html5test.com/).  So if your target audience does not have access to a modern browser, HTML5 would definitely be a disadvantage.  This is also the major disadvantage of using CSS3.

The advantages certainly outweigh the cons.  This is an excellent resource that outlines many of the differences and advantages of using HTML5 - http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/  This site has the major advantages of CSS3 over CSS - http://www.magentojunction.com/blog/advantages-of-css3-over-css/

Comment: Hmmm doesn't the second and third disadvantage apply to version 4 as well?

Comment: @Jonathon You're right.  I guess I was referring to the disadvantages of HTML5 in general.

Comment: @RyanMiller Sorry to be pedantic but you're talking about HTML in general right? Don't want Tausif to get the wrong impression that HTML4 has those things, or that it has anything that the newer version doesn't have for that matter.

Comment: @JonathanChua I removed those last two disadvantages.  The answer now addresses HTML5 vs earlier HTML directly.

Comment: While we're being pedantic, I should add that CSS3 **is** CSS anyway, so it doesn't really make sense to compare them. Whether you're using HTML5 or HTML 4 doesn't change what you can do with CSS - the same styling language is compatible with both markup languages.

Comment: @BoltClock Like HTML5 **is** just HTML, but there are specific sections of the markup which won't work in older browsers. The comparison is which will work vs which is better.